# AWS Lambda and Redis client. Why can't I call callback?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write an AWS Lambda function which uses Redis. When I run the code below:

```
'use strict'

function handler (data, context, callback) {
  const redis = require("redis")
  const _ = require("lodash")
  console.log('before client')
  const client = redis.createClient({
    url: 'redis://cache-url.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379',
  })
  console.log('after client')
  callback(null, {status: 'result'})
  console.log('after callback')
}

exports.handler = handler
```

I have an answer like this:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2016-09-20T15:22:27.301Z 07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

and logs look like:

```

17:22:24
START RequestId: 07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da Version: $LATEST

17:22:26
2016-09-20T15:22:26.014Z    07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da    before client

17:22:26
2016-09-20T15:22:26.134Z    07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da    after client

17:22:26
2016-09-20T15:22:26.135Z    07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da    after callback

17:22:27
END RequestId: 07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da

17:22:27
REPORT RequestId: 07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da  Duration: 3001.81 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 24 MB

17:22:27
2016-09-20T15:22:27.301Z 07d24e0b-7f46-11e6-85e9-e5f48906c0da Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

which, IMHO, means that callback was called but nothing happened.

When I remove client's initialization I see proper response.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I never use Redis, but be aware that Lambda is a stateless services. Be care about creating clients and opening connections. A few months ago i try to do the same with a MongoDB, but i found the problem in the connections. I don't know if is the same here.

Comment: Yep, I know. But I'm creating a connection on every call(inside handler). An if there is no way to use db's(except dynamoDB) it makes it useless

Comment: It's exactly what I thought when I had the problem with MongoDB. Even using a RDS is a problem. I believe, if you are not using the AWS SDK and making a hundred of api calls, is not worthy to use. As i see, lambda only works good with stateless services, and BD are not stateless. Hope someone tell us more.

Comment: is cache-url.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 reachable within lambda? check that you have given proper inbound configurations to your redis instance.

Comment: I think, the problem is the context. See this article: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/getting-nodejs-and-lambda-to-play-nicely/

Comment: @manuerumx that's an old article that applies to an older version of Lambda and NodeJS. See my answer for the actual resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html):

> When the callback is called, the Lambda function exits only after the
>   Node.js event loop is empty.

Since you are calling the callback, but your Lambda function invocation is not ending, it appears you still have something on the event loop. Your function isn't really doing anything except creating a Redis connection. I'm guessing you need to close the Redis connection when you are done with it, in order to clear the event loop and allow the Lambda invocation to complete.

Comment: yep, I'm simplified my code to minimum viable sample. I'll try to close connection and return to you